# Swift umbrella header from another target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a project with several targets. The main target is a combination of Swift and Objective-C classes and objc files, which use Swift classes by including the ModuleName-Swift.h umbrella header. However, when I include the same source files to several targets the umbrella header can't be found in other than the main target. The module name in the header import should be different for each target. How do I achieve this?

**Update:**

So far I have not found any other way than setting the same Product Module Name for all targets. That does not seem to have any side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when writing a Today Extension for my app.
I have a file named for example Items.swift located at Today extension component and
included to that target. So I have following situation: Main project fully written on Objective-C
and Today extension is written on Swift

### Problem:

I want to include file Items.swift to main project and use it

### Solution:

1. Make sure that `Items.swift` is included to main app target
2. Important (**!!!**) you should create `"ProductModuleName"-Bridging-Header.h` and add reference to this file in project file (Objective-C Bridging Header option) even if your
   main target contain only Objective-C code
3. Your `Items.swift` should inherit from NSObject or its descendants
4. Than add `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` to place where you want
   to use `Items.swift` and press Build

Finally you can go to `"ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` and make sure that interface is generated than you can use your Objective-C version of your class

ProductModuleName you can see at Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Module Name

Comment: If I have so many files in main target and its in `objc` and need to add all these files to today extension How I can add that files withoutrepeatation of files

Comment: @Rafeek, you can't. today extension is ANOTHER project. So, you need to create framework part from your main project and add this framework to your today extension

Comment: This does not answer my question for including the same umbrella header in the same files, which are just added to different targets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to clear up the confusion that `ModuleName-Swift.h` is Swift compiler generated header that is used to use swift code in Objective-C and umbrella header   `ModuleName.h` is the header for framework targets to expose Objective-C code to Swift.

Regardless, as I understand your question you want to import a header that is a form of target name, in files that are shared across multiple targets. For this you can define a preprocessor macro with different value for each target and in your Obective-C file use the macro value to imprt the header, i.e. `#import macro`.

Let's say for your example you want to import swift generated header `ModuleName-Swift.h` in your shared files. The generated header name is available in build settings as `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME`. You can create a macro `SWIFT_HEADER` for that header name in preprocessor macros section(`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`):

```
# '\' is important to preserve '"'
SWIFT_HEADER=\"$(SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME)\"
```

and then in your Objective-C files import using this macro:

```objectivec
#import SWIFT_HEADER
```

Additionally, you can create a single xcconfig adding this preprocessor macro and share it for all the targets:

```
# '\' is important to preserve '"'
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) SWIFT_HEADER=\"$(SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME)\"
```